# Listing analytics for Goo.gl's url shortening API

Tags: javascript, api, list, url-shortener

I've been digging through Google's docs on its url shortener API, but to no avail.
I'm trying to avoid using oAuth and just javascript to list the statistics.
In theory, it should be possible to list statistics for all urls shortened with a specific API key, but I get a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Can anyone tell me if this is possible — or how I could list all url shortened stats for a specific domain, using just JS and an API key as authorisation?

Sample request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url/history?key=myAPIkey&start-token=10&projection=FULL
```

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation says: "**This request requires authorization** with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#auth))." When you follow the link to read more, it says:

> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), **then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request**. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.

So, you need to provide OAuth tokens to use the `url/list` resource ([but not `url/get`, so have a look at that](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/get)).